# Files not found when launching from remote PC

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to use a launchfile to launch ROS nodes on two seperate machines, the remote PC cannot find the files I want to launch. I have also installed both packages on both machines for testing purpouses. The files is can be launched on both PC's, but when I try to launch them remotely, they're not found.

I have looked at a lot of other people using ROS on two machines, but I cannot seem to find any solution to this problem. Any suggestions/help is appreciated. All necessary files is listed below.

EDIT: I have tried launching the turtlesim teleop node on the remote PC, a node that is native in ROS. This works with no problem, so the problem lies in custom made nodes.

EDIT: Added the "printenv" variables from manually

**Main launch file**

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find r18dv_tf_publisher)/hosts/hosts.machine" />
  <node machine="tegra_a" pkg="r18dv_tf_publisher" type="tf_broadcaster" name="tf_broadcaster" />
  <node machine="tegra_b" pkg="r18dv_simple_heading_controller" type="r18dv_simple_heading_controller_node" name="heading_controller" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

**hosts.machine**

```
<launch>
  <machine name="tegra_a" address="10.42.0.28" env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh" />
  <machine name="tegra_b" address="10.42.0.29" env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh" />
</launch>
```

The file structure is identical on the two machines, and both env.sh files is located at the same location.

**env.sh on tegra_a**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
  /bin/echo "Usage: env.sh COMMANDS"
  /bin/echo "Calling env.sh without arguments is not supported anymore. Instead spawn a subshell and source a setup file manually."
  exit 1
fi

# ensure to not use different shell type which was set before
CATKIN_SHELL=sh

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(cd "`dirname "$0"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"

export ROS_WS=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws
export ROS_KINETIC=/etc/ros/kinetic
source $ROS_WS/devel/setup.bash
source $ROS_KINETIC/setup.bash
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$ROS_WS
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311/
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.42.0.28
exec "$@"
```

**env.sh on tegra_b**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
  /bin/echo "Usage: env.sh COMMANDS"
  /bin/echo "Calling env.sh without arguments is not supported anymore. Instead spawn a subshell and source a setup file manually."
  exit 1
fi

# ensure to not use different shell type which was set before
CATKIN_SHELL=sh

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(cd "`dirname "$0"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"

export ROS_WS=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws
export ROS_KINETIC=/etc/ros/kinetic
source $ROS_WS/devel/setup.bash
source $ROS_KINETIC/setup.bash
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$ROS_WS
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311/
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.42.0.29
exec "$@"
```

**Output when launching the launchfile**

```
nvidia@nvidia:/opt/ros/kinetic$ roslaunch r18dv_tf_publisher test_launch.launch 
... logging to /home/nvidia/.ros/log/3dfcc3a4-fba0-11e7-8f39-00044b8da45f/roslaunch-nvidia-8089.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.42.0.28:33233/
remote[10.42.0.29-0] starting roslaunch
remote[10.42.0.29-0]: creating ssh connection to 10.42.0.29:22
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py:141: FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV
  self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [env ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311/ /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh roslaunch -c 10.42.0.29-0 -u http://10.42.0.28:33233/ --run_id 3dfcc3a4-fba0-11e7-8f39-00044b8da45f]
remote[10.42.0.29-0]: ssh connection created

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.12

MACHINES
 * tegra_a
 * tegra_b

NODES
  /
    heading_controller (r18dv_simple_heading_controller/r18dv_simple_heading_controller_node)
    tf_broadcaster (r18dv_tf_publisher/tf_broadcaster)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [8104]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311/

setting /run_id to 3dfcc3a4-fba0-11e7-8f39-00044b8da45f
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [8117]
started core service [/rosout]
process[tf_broadcaster-2]: started with pid [8128]
[10.42.0.29-0]: launching nodes...
[10.42.0.29-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311/
[10.42.0.29-0]: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [r18dv_simple_heading_controller/r18dv_simple_heading_controller_node]: can't locate node [r18dv_simple_heading_controller_node] in package [r18dv_simple_heading_controller]
[10.42.0.29-0]: ... done launching nodes
```

**printenv when manually ssh'ing into tegra_b:**

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=1
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
SSH_CLIENT=10.42.0.28 51856 22
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/4
USER=nvidia
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL=/var/mail/nvidia
PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
PWD=/home/nvidia/Documents
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/nvidia
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
PYTHONPATH=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
LOGNAME=nvidia
ROS_IP=10.42.0.29
SSH_CONNECTION=10.42.0.28 51856 10.42.0.29 22
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XAUTHORITY=/home/nvidia/.Xauthority
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
_=/usr/bin/printenv
OLDPWD=/home/nvidia
```

**printenv in the env.sh file on the tegra_b:**

```
    MAIL=/var/mail/nvidia 
    SSH_CLIENT=10.42.0.28 53326 22
    USER=nvidia
    ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share:/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src
    SHLVL=1
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib
    ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
    HOME=/home/nvidia
    ROS_IP=10.42.0.29
    ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
    LOGNAME=nvidia
    _=/usr/bin/env
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig
    XDG_SESSION_ID=9
 PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
    ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
    ROS_KINETIC=/etc/ros/kinetic
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    ROS_WS=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws
    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311/
    PWD=/home/nvidia
    SSH_CONNECTION=10.42.0.28 53326 10.42.0.29 22
    PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280193/files-not-found-when-launching-from-remote-pc/) by [DidrikSG](https://answers.ros.org/users/33339/didriksg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### I found the error, and it is (of course) a simple and dumb mistake

In the `<machine>` tag, I set the `env-loader` to use the `env.sh` file in `/opt/ros/kinetic/`, but as this executes and uses the `setup.sh` file in the same folder as the `env.sh` file. The `env.sh` file in the rosdistro will not find files in your catkin_ws. By changing the path to the `env.sh` file to `/home/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh`, and updated the `env.sh` file to the same as listed in my original question, everything worked as it should (note that all the other mistakes also needed to be fixed for everything to work as well)

**Correct and tested hosts.machine file**

```
<launch>
  <machine name="tegra_a" address="10.42.0.28" env-loader="/home/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh" />
  <machine name="tegra_b" address="10.42.0.29" env-loader="/home/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh" />
</launch>
```

**Correct and tested env.sh file in `/home/catkin_ws/devel/` on tegra_b**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
  /bin/echo "Usage: env.sh COMMANDS"
  /bin/echo "Calling env.sh without arguments is not supported anymore. Instead spawn a subshell and source a setup file manually."
  exit 1
fi

# ensure to not use different shell type which was set before
CATKIN_SHELL=sh

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(cd "`dirname "$0"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"

export ROS_WS=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws
export ROS_KINETIC=/etc/ros/kinetic
source $ROS_WS/devel/setup.bash
source $ROS_KINETIC/setup.bash
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$ROS_WS
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.28:11311/
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.42.0.29
exec "$@"
```

---

Originally posted by [DidrikSG](https://answers.ros.org/users/33339/didriksg/) with karma: 71 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're sourcing the ros setup and workspace setup files in the wrong order.

```
source $ROS_WS/devel/setup.bash
source $ROS_KINETIC/setup.bash
```

The main ros **setup.bash** will overwrite the workspace setup, so you always want to source the workspace **setup.bash** file second.

**Update** thanks for the new information. There are two differences that look like they might be causing the problem. ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES is blank when setup using 'env.sh' the other is that the order of the paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is reversed. If i had to guess the missing ROSLISP path is looking the most suspicious.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DidrikSG](https://answers.ros.org/users/33339/didriksg/) on 2018-01-19**:
Hi Pete. I changed the order on both env.sh files, but I still get the same output

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-19**:\

> [..] so you always want to source the workspace setup.bash file second.

yes, and you don't even need to `source` the one in `/opt/ros/$distro` ..

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-19**:
Just to check can you roslaunch the files individually if you ssh in without any problems? If so try a **printenv** here when you're ssh'ed in and another **printenv** to a log file in the **env.sh** script. If there are any differences they might be the source of the problem.

**Comment by [DidrikSG](https://answers.ros.org/users/33339/didriksg/) on 2018-01-19**:
I have no problem launching the files individually, but I suspect that there might be a difference in the env's.  The variables from manually sshing in and writing "printenv" and the "printenv" from the env.sh file is now added in the question.

**Comment by [DidrikSG](https://answers.ros.org/users/33339/didriksg/) on 2018-01-21**:
Hi Pete! Thank you for the updated information! I tried changing the order on the two paths in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and I also exported the correct ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES in the env.sh file, but this did not fix the problem, and I get the same output as before

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Perhaps too late, but I hope it helps somebody.

You can configure the environment of a machine from only one env.sh, in this case as @DidrikSG was trying, from /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh

If we read carefully, everything that env.sh is dong is running the setup.sh on the same folder, so we only need to run the setup.sh of all the workspaces we need.

In my case, running a node in TegraA from TegraB:

**TegraB:**

```
export ROS_IP=10.42.0.29
roslaunch test.launch
```

**test.launch** is something like:

```
<launch> 
   <machine name="nvidiaTA" address="10.42.0.28" env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh" user="nvidia" /> 
   <node machine="nvidiaTA" name="gmsl_n_cameras_node" pkg="gmsl_n_cameras" type="gmsl_n_cameras_node" /> 
  ...
</launch>
```

and

**TegraA**

In **/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh** I only added:

```
. /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh
export ROS_IP=10.42.0.28
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.29:11311
```

So,  @DidrikSG in your /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh just add:

```
. /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh
```

and as many workspaces you need

I hope it helps!

Regards

---

Originally posted by [DavidTorresOcana](https://answers.ros.org/users/36987/davidtorresocana/) with karma: 31 on 2018-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1